# Создание таблицы и использование переменной в названии поля

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день друзья! Прошу помощи

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$idareid = 'idare'.$id;
$q = "CREATE TABLE `$idareid` (
`$idareid`.`_id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`data_num` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(`$idareid`.`_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";
```

ругается

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.`_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1'
>   at line 28

Comment: Вы, видимо, не весь код показываете. То, что у вас написано в принципе работать не может

Comment: Тут проблема только в переменной $idareid. Я не знаю как правильно ее написать. Конечно там несколько полей, я их не скопировал просто.

Comment: речь скорее о том, как вы выполняеете вообще этот запрос на `create`. у вас приведен пхп в перемешку с отдельными частями SQL. Напишите код полностью.

Comment: либо вам тут явно не хватает вызова `mysql_query(" create table ...")`

Comment: $id = mysql_insert_id();
    $idareid = 'idare'.$id;
    $q = "CREATE TABLE `$idareid` (
   `$idareid`.`_id` tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `data_num` varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`$idareid`.`_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";

Comment: изменил код чтобы было понятнее

Comment: точки там у вас лишние в ```$idareid`.`_id```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$idareid = 'idare'.$id;

$q = "CREATE TABLE " . $idareid . " (
" . $idareid . "_id tinyint(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
data_num varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(" . $idareid ."_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";
```

Comment: Оказывается и так можно :) Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов :)

Comment: Спасибо!!! И вам !!!